# how do sum every Column in Sql Sevrer?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Every record amount sum into Total column

```
  id            Amount           total
  --------------------------------------------
  1              100            100              
  1              50             150         
  1              60             210        
  1              10             220      
  2              70             290
  2              10             300
```

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want window function :

```
select t.*, 
       sum(amount) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as total
from table t;
```